# command print button. When I click on the print button,the first page prints twice other pages print single which is what I want

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 concerns, if someone can assist. I am new to VBA. I have a command print button on my excel sheet and I added the code listed below. When I click on the print button, I have the first page print twice but the rest of the pages print single which is what I want. How do I fix the code so it only prints once.
The other thing is when the print manager window opens for me to select a printer, I would like to have the code select single page print and not duplex printing. The printer default settings are set for duplex and I dont want to change that setting through windows but for the code to automatically select single sided prints.

Thank you,

```
Private Sub PrintAll_Click()

    Dim rngOffenders As Range
    Set rngOffenders = Worksheets("Names").Range("A2", Worksheets("Names").Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    Dim willPrint As Boolean
        willPrint = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
        If Not willPrint Then Exit Sub

    Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In rngOffenders.Cells
        Worksheets("Template").Range("LastName").Value = rng.Value
        Calculate
        Worksheets("Template").PrintOut
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess, without testing, is that by `Show` the print dialog, you're invoking print against the first/active sheet once you press "OK". Then, as you iterate over `rngOffenders.Cells`, you're printing that sheet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the duplicate printing, my guess, without testing, is that by `Show` the print dialog, you're invoking print against the first/active sheet once you press "OK". Then, as you iterate over `rngOffenders.Cells`, you're printing that sheet again. So, you could start at the second cell in `rngOffenders` to avoid that.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To rngOffenders.Cells.Count
    Worksheets("Template").Range("LastName").Value = rngOffenders.Cells(i).Value
    Calculate
    Worksheets("Template").PrintOut
Next rng
```

For the printer settings, that is more complicated. See [here](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/SetDuplexOnOff.htm):

> The best way of doing this is by using API calls. The following article gives you a VB code sample which does this:
>
> [Q230743](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=230743)
>
> Only one “problem” with this code: It is written for VB and uses Printer.DeviceName to return the name of the currently selected printer. In Word VBA, you need to substitute this with ActivePrinter. The problem is that the strings returned by these commands are slightly different, even though they both get the name of the printer from the name assigned in Control Panel | Printers. For instance.:
>
> **ActivePrinter:** HP LaserJet 6L PCL on LPT1:
>
> **Printer.DeviceName:** HP LaserJet 6L PCL
>
> So you'll need to test and modify the code sample accordingly.
>
> If you don't want to use API calls, however, you can install a duplicate printer driver with the duplex property set and print to that (by changing the ActivePrinter).

The linked KB article demonstrates (at length) how to *set* the printer to duplex printing. Most of the same code should be used for the inverse operation, you'd just need to figure out what value to pass for that property.

## Test Procedure:

Place this in a standard module. Note the possible need to adjust the length of printer string (removing the port component e.g., "HP Ink Jet Fantastico **on LP02**", etc.)

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim pName As String
    pName = ActivePrinter
    ' Note you may need to adjust this value to remove the port string component
    pName = Left(pName, (Len(pName) - 9))
        
    SetPrinterDuplex pName, 1  '1 = NOT duplex printing.

    'Here you might want to actually print something, for example:
    Worksheets("Template").PrintOut

End Sub
```

In a separate module, place all of the printer-related code. NB: I am on a machine with no printer access, so I am unable to test or further debug this solution.

```
Option Explicit

   Public Type PRINTER_DEFAULTS

       pDatatype As Long
       pDevmode As Long
       DesiredAccess As Long
   End Type

   Public Type PRINTER_INFO_2
       pServerName As Long
       pPrinterName As Long
       pShareName As Long
       pPortName As Long
       pDriverName As Long
       pComment As Long
       pLocation As Long
       pDevmode As Long       ' Pointer to DEVMODE
       pSepFile As Long
       pPrintProcessor As Long
       pDatatype As Long
       pParameters As Long
       pSecurityDescriptor As Long  ' Pointer to SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR
       Attributes As Long
       Priority As Long
       DefaultPriority As Long
       StartTime As Long
       UntilTime As Long
       Status As Long
       cJobs As Long
       AveragePPM As Long
   End Type

   Public Type DEVMODE
       dmDeviceName As String * 32
       dmSpecVersion As Integer
       dmDriverVersion As Integer
       dmSize As Integer
       dmDriverExtra As Integer
       dmFields As Long
       dmOrientation As Integer
       dmPaperSize As Integer
       dmPaperLength As Integer
       dmPaperWidth As Integer
       dmScale As Integer
       dmCopies As Integer
       dmDefaultSource As Integer
       dmPrintQuality As Integer
       dmColor As Integer
       dmDuplex As Integer
       dmYResolution As Integer
       dmTTOption As Integer
       dmCollate As Integer
       dmFormName As String * 32
       dmUnusedPadding As Integer
       dmBitsPerPel As Integer
       dmPelsWidth As Long
       dmPelsHeight As Long
       dmDisplayFlags As Long
       dmDisplayFrequency As Long
       dmICMMethod As Long
       dmICMIntent As Long
       dmMediaType As Long
       dmDitherType As Long
       dmReserved1 As Long
       dmReserved2 As Long
   End Type

   Public Const DM_DUPLEX = &H1000&
   Public Const DM_IN_BUFFER = 8

   Public Const DM_OUT_BUFFER = 2
   Public Const PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = &H4
   Public Const PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = &H8
   Public Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = &HF0000
   Public Const PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED Or _
             PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER Or PRINTER_ACCESS_USE)

   Public Declare Function ClosePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
    (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
   Public Declare Function DocumentProperties Lib "winspool.drv" _
     Alias "DocumentPropertiesA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal pDeviceName As String, _
     ByVal pDevModeOutput As Long, ByVal pDevModeInput As Long, _
     ByVal fMode As Long) As Long
   Public Declare Function GetPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
     "GetPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal Level As Long, _
     pPrinter As Byte, ByVal cbBuf As Long, pcbNeeded As Long) As Long
   Public Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
     "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, phPrinter As Long, _
     pDefault As PRINTER_DEFAULTS) As Long
   Public Declare Function SetPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
     "SetPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal Level As Long, _
     pPrinter As Byte, ByVal Command As Long) As Long

   Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (pDest As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal cbLength As Long)
 
   ' ==================================================================
   ' SetPrinterDuplex
   '
   '  Programmatically set the Duplex flag for the specified printer
   '  driver's default properties.
   '
   '  Returns: True on success, False on error. (An error will also

   '  display a message box. This is done for informational value
   '  only. You should modify the code to support better error
   '  handling in your production application.)
   '
   '  Parameters:
   '    sPrinterName - The name of the printer to be used.
   '
   '    nDuplexSetting - One of the following standard settings:
   '       1 = None
   '       2 = Duplex on long edge (book)
   '       3 = Duplex on short edge (legal)
   '
   ' ==================================================================
   Public Function SetPrinterDuplex(ByVal sPrinterName As String, _
       ByVal nDuplexSetting As Long) As Boolean

      Dim hPrinter As Long
      Dim pd As PRINTER_DEFAULTS
      Dim pinfo As PRINTER_INFO_2
      Dim dm As DEVMODE
   
      Dim yDevModeData() As Byte
      Dim yPInfoMemory() As Byte
      Dim nBytesNeeded As Long
      Dim nRet As Long, nJunk As Long
   
      On Error GoTo cleanup
   
'#### I removed this block because it was preventing you from changing the duplex settings
'      If (nDuplexSetting < 1) Or (nDuplexSetting > 3) Then
'         MsgBox "Error: dwDuplexSetting is incorrect."
'         Exit Function
'      End If
'####

      pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS
      nRet = OpenPrinter(sPrinterName, hPrinter, pd)
      If (nRet = 0) Or (hPrinter = 0) Then
         If Err.LastDllError = 5 Then
            MsgBox "Access denied -- See the article for more info."
         Else
            MsgBox "Cannot open the printer specified " & _
              "(make sure the printer name is correct)."
         End If
         Exit Function
      End If
   
      nRet = DocumentProperties(0, hPrinter, sPrinterName, 0, 0, 0)
      If (nRet < 0) Then
         MsgBox "Cannot get the size of the DEVMODE structure."
         GoTo cleanup
      End If
   
      ReDim yDevModeData(nRet + 100) As Byte
      nRet = DocumentProperties(0, hPrinter, sPrinterName, _
                  VarPtr(yDevModeData(0)), 0, DM_OUT_BUFFER)
      If (nRet < 0) Then
         MsgBox "Cannot get the DEVMODE structure."
         GoTo cleanup
      End If
   
      Call CopyMemory(dm, yDevModeData(0), Len(dm))
   
      If Not CBool(dm.dmFields And DM_DUPLEX) Then
        MsgBox "You cannot modify the duplex flag for this printer " & _
               "because it does not support duplex or the driver " & _
               "does not support setting it from the Windows API."
         GoTo cleanup
      End If
   
      dm.dmDuplex = nDuplexSetting
      Call CopyMemory(yDevModeData(0), dm, Len(dm))
   
      nRet = DocumentProperties(0, hPrinter, sPrinterName, _
        VarPtr(yDevModeData(0)), VarPtr(yDevModeData(0)), _
        DM_IN_BUFFER Or DM_OUT_BUFFER)

      If (nRet < 0) Then
        MsgBox "Unable to set duplex setting to this printer."
        GoTo cleanup
      End If
   
      Call GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, 0, 0, nBytesNeeded)
      If (nBytesNeeded = 0) Then GoTo cleanup
   
      ReDim yPInfoMemory(nBytesNeeded + 100) As Byte

      nRet = GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, yPInfoMemory(0), nBytesNeeded, nJunk)
      If (nRet = 0) Then
         MsgBox "Unable to get shared printer settings."
         GoTo cleanup
      End If
   
      Call CopyMemory(pinfo, yPInfoMemory(0), Len(pinfo))
      pinfo.pDevmode = VarPtr(yDevModeData(0))
      pinfo.pSecurityDescriptor = 0
      Call CopyMemory(yPInfoMemory(0), pinfo, Len(pinfo))
   
      nRet = SetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, yPInfoMemory(0), 0)
      If (nRet = 0) Then
         MsgBox "Unable to set shared printer settings."
      End If
   
      SetPrinterDuplex = CBool(nRet)

cleanup:
      If (hPrinter <> 0) Then Call ClosePrinter(hPrinter)

   End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You can print the first page twice like this:

```
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim lpc As Long

lpc = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count

 For i = 1 To lpc + 1
    If i = 1 Then
    k = 2
    Else
    k = 1
    End If
ActiveSheet.PrintOut from:=i, To:=i, Copies:=k
 Next
```